# Why doesn't my PrimeFaces app look the same as the showcase?

Tags: css, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 8 and I can't get the same design as that of showcase. Which CSS should I declare?

### My application

[image]

### Showcase

[image]

Comment: Did you see your 'answer' was removed and what the better way is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces comes with several free themes. You can see them in action at the [`themeSwitcher` showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml). If you don't configure a theme, [PrimeFaces 8 will use the (legacy) theme `aristo` by default](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/8.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/HeadRenderer.java#L87). The theme the showcase uses by default is `nova-light`. To make your application look the same as the showcase, [configure your theme](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/gettingstarted/configuration) to be `nova-light`. So, in your `web.xml` add:

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>nova-light</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Once you've set a theme, you can [override the default theme styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles) if you need to.